# Using an appropriate hypothesis to test whether two means are different

Tags: statistics, normal-distribution, random-variables

Manager examined potential differences between two models of bicycles. The 
mean life of the bicycles is of primary concern. The followings table provides the 
available date which measured in thousands of miles:

Sample size　　Sample mean　　Sample standard deviation

Model A　　　　$80$　　　　　　$50.2$　　　　　　　　$2.6$

Model B　　　　$64$　　　　　　$47.8$　　　　　　　　$4.0$

1. I know how to test a mean, but how to determine by using an appropriate hypothesis whether the mean lives of the two brands are different? To create a new random variable $A-B$ and see whether $A-B=0$? (denote the mean life of Model A by $A$, and that of Model B by $B$) Also which two appropriate significance levels should I test at?
2. Should I assume they are normally distributed?
3. How about to determine whether the mean life of the bicycles 
   of model B is longer than that of the model A bicycles? Is it correct to test whether $B-A>0$? (denote the mean life of Model A by $A$, and that of Model B by $B$)

Comment: this is homework.
Look up large sample hypothesis tests on two means. It's certain to be in your textbook.

Comment: @alice: That does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post - you can always comment on your own posts, and once you have sufficient [reputation](http://math.stackexchange.com/faq#reputation) you will be able to [comment on any post](http://math.stackexchange.com/privileges/comment).

Comment: This is a homeworklike question but not my homework, I didn't get any textbooks on it, just study online. So can you help? or is my direction correct?